# how to add attribute for all subnodes of the xml in sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have a xml like below in a variable @xml

```
<ContentTemplate>
  <Tab Title="Lesson">
    <Section Title="Lesson Opening" />
    <Section Title="Lesson/Activity" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="Wrap Up and Assessment">
    <Section Title="Lesson Closing" />
    <Section Title="Tracking Progress/Daily Assessment" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="Differentiated Instruction">
    <Section Title="Strategies - Keyword" />
    <Section Title="Strategies – Text" />
    <Section Title="Resources" />
    <Section Title="Acceleration/Enrichment" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="District Resources">
    <Section Title="Related Content Items" />
    <Section Title="Other" />
  </Tab>
</ContentTemplate>
```

I want to insert an attribute for all tab nodes in the above xml..
    the output should be like below:

```
<ContentTemplate>
      <Tab Title="Lesson" PortletName="CommunitiesViewer">
        <Section Title="Lesson Opening" />
        <Section Title="Lesson/Activity" />
      </Tab>
      <Tab Title="Wrap Up and Assessment" PortletName="CommunitiesViewer">
        <Section Title="Lesson Closing" />
        <Section Title="Tracking Progress/Daily Assessment" />
      </Tab>
      <Tab Title="Differentiated Instruction" PortletName="CommunitiesViewer">
        <Section Title="Strategies - Keyword" />
        <Section Title="Strategies – Text" />
        <Section Title="Resources" />
        <Section Title="Acceleration/Enrichment" />
      </Tab>
      <Tab Title="District Resources" PortletName="CommunitiesViewer">
        <Section Title="Related Content Items" />
        <Section Title="Other" />
      </Tab>
    </ContentTemplate>
```

i tried the following code to get the above xml

```
set @xml.modify( 'insert attribute PortletName {sql:variable("@PortletName")} into (ContentTemplate/Tab)[1]')
```

its just update the first sub node.

how to update all the sub nodes of the xml..

thanks in advance

Comment: Btw: This is a good question. There is test code for copy'n'paste, input and expected output and some own effort. +1 from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML in a variable

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<ContentTemplate>
  <Tab Title="Lesson">
    <Section Title="Lesson Opening" />
    <Section Title="Lesson/Activity" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="Wrap Up and Assessment">
    <Section Title="Lesson Closing" />
    <Section Title="Tracking Progress/Daily Assessment" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="Differentiated Instruction">
    <Section Title="Strategies - Keyword" />
    <Section Title="Strategies – Text" />
    <Section Title="Resources" />
    <Section Title="Acceleration/Enrichment" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="District Resources">
    <Section Title="Related Content Items" />
    <Section Title="Other" />
  </Tab>
</ContentTemplate>';
```

### 1) [FLWOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx)

The `.modify()`-statement allows you to change one decent point in your XML, but you'd need many calls to change many places. FLWOR allows you to re-build the XML out of itself:

```
SET @xml=@xml.query(
'<ContentTemplate>
{
for $t in /ContentTemplate/Tab
   return 
   <Tab Title="{$t/@Title}" PortletName="CommunitiesViewer">
   {$t/*}
   </Tab>
}
</ContentTemplate>');

SELECT @xml
```

### 2) Rebuild with `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH()`

You'd reach the same with this approach: Again the XML is re-built, but this time it is shredded and used as a new `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH`

```
SELECT tb.value('@Title','nvarchar(max)') AS [@Title]
      ,'CommunitiesViewer' AS [@PortletName]
      ,tb.query('*')
FROM @xml.nodes('/ContentTemplate/Tab') AS A(tb)
FOR XML PATH('Tab'),ROOT('ContentTemplate')
```

Comment: Thank you for a 1st method. Works fast and perfectly. Saved my day.