# Add variable as attribute to subnodes of a XML in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, flwor

I am trying to add the value of a pre-defined variable to each individual subnode of my XML. I found this question [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111130/how-to-add-attribute-for-all-subnodes-of-the-xml-in-sql) and its answer, which looks pretty neat to me.

However, I can't use the variable `@modification_time` as an input for the attribute.

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<ContentTemplate>
  <Tab Title="Lesson">
    <Section Title="Lesson Opening" />
    <Section Title="Lesson/Activity" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="Wrap Up and Assessment">
    <Section Title="Lesson Closing" />
    <Section Title="Tracking Progress/Daily Assessment" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="Differentiated Instruction">
    <Section Title="Strategies - Keyword" />
    <Section Title="Strategies – Text" />
    <Section Title="Resources" />
    <Section Title="Acceleration/Enrichment" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="District Resources">
    <Section Title="Related Content Items" />
    <Section Title="Other" />
  </Tab>
</ContentTemplate>';
```

I can't figure out if it's possible and how to add the variable value to the subnode.

```sql
DECLARE @modification_time nvarchar(30); 
SET @modification_time = FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss' ) ;  

SET @xml=@xml.query(
'<ContentTemplate>
{
for $t in /ContentTemplate/Tab
   return 
   <Tab Title="{$t/@Title}" PortletName="CommunitiesViewer" ModificationTime="VariableValuehere" >
   {$t/*}
   </Tab>
}
</ContentTemplate>');

SELECT @xml
```

Comment: Try `sql:variable("@modification_time")`, no time to type an answer in full a.t.m. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Unfortunately, `ModificationTime=sql:variable("@modification_time")` is not working and fails with `XQuery [query()]: A string literal was expected`. I've also experimented with adding ' + to the string, but that does not work either.

Comment: `ModificationTime="{sql:variable("@modification_time")}"` works, found it on https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15#using-the-let-clause